# Stop Eclipse/Gradle from generating .project and .settings/

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

I once installed Eclipse a few days ago on my Ubuntu machine and decided to remove it, but now there's a `.setting/` directory and `.project` file in my android project repository and it is generated again after removing it using `rm` command. How should I stop it?

Comment: how do you open the project?

Comment: I open it via android studio, but even navigating to it via terminal would cause the same.

Comment: why don't you issue an `ignore` command in your repository?

Comment: You mean adding the file to `.gitignore` file?

Comment: probably. i dont know how to do it in git.

Comment: I don't want to clear the question, I want a solution.

Comment: Probably the files are created by Gradle. Search for `eclipse` in your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `build.gradle` file has the Gradle Eclipse plugin referenced? This would be the only reason why those files keep getting generated even if you stopped using Eclipse. If this is the case, compare your Gradle build to a previous version, or simply remove the [Eclipse plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html).

If you are still using Eclipse, or any Eclipse based IDE, those files will keep getting generated and I wouldn't recommend deleting them. As suggested earlier, you *can* prevent them from getting into your source control system. If using Git, you can add the following to your `.gitignore` file to have these files ignored.

```
.project
.settings
```

Comment: How should I remove eclipse plugins?

Comment: Edit the build.gradle file and remove the references. My answer had a link to documentation that will be helpful, and much faster than asking here.

Comment: I asked cause there's not a reference to eclipse plugin in my `build.gradle` file and I don't have a root settings in `~/.gradle`.